# Remove and add CSS File

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am removing a css file and adding the file on click

To remove the file I am using

```
$('link[title="mystyle"]').remove();
```

Is there any way to add that file back to DOM once its removed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about not removing it, instead only remove the source `href`?

```
// remove
$('link[title="mystyle"]').data("href", $('link[title="mystyle"]').attr("href")).attr("href", "");

// bring back
$('link[title="mystyle"]').attr("href", $('link[title="mystyle"]').data("href"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just keep a reference to it, and `append`/`appendTo` it when you want to put it back.

Removing:

```
var link = $('link[title="mystyle"]').remove();
```

Later, when you want to put it back:

```
link.appendTo('head');
```

Here's an example doing that with the `style` element in a Stack Snippet, but it works the same for `link`:

```js
var style = null;
setInterval(function() {
  if (style) {
    style.appendTo('head');
    style = null;
  } else {
    style = $("style").remove();
  }
}, 800);
```

```css
p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Testing 1 2 3</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `var link = $('link[title="mystyle"]')` ? then `link.remove()`?

Comment: @Riad: [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/), like most jQuery methods, returns a reference to the object, so we don't have to do it separately. We *can*, but we don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var link = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + YourFileName + '">'
$('head').append(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<link id="custom" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<a href="#" id="changeCss">Change CSS</a>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#changeCss').click(function(){
  if($('#custom').attr('href') != ''){
    $('#custom').attr('href', '');
  }else {$('#custom').attr('href', 'style.css')}
  return false;
})
```

Hope useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the stylesheet’s URL, there’s various alternatives:

```js
var url = '//cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/all.css';

/* Insert as HTML string: */
document.head.insertAdjacentHTML(
    'beforeend',
    '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + url + '">'
);

/* Or, after removal, create a link element and append it: */
var styleLink = document.createElement('link');
styleLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
styleLink.type = 'text/css';
styleLink.href = url;
document.head.appendChild(styleLink);

/* Or, remove it with jQuery and save its reference: */
var linkElement = $('link[title="mystyle"]').remove();
linkElement.appendTo('head');
```